# The physics of tripping on a stone

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life

You know, you are walking or running at a certain velocity, your foot gets stuck on an obstacle and you end up flat-faced to the ground.

What is the physics behind it? How does the linear motion change into rotational motion? Probably the formula for an ideal body tripping is simple; is there any energy subtracted from linear motion and given to the stone? Or is it just $\omega = \sqrt{2E_k/I}$?

Comment: Why would there be "energy wasted on the stone"? Are you moving the stone? Are you compressing it significantly?

Comment: There is no need for any friction between the stone and the foot in order to trip.

Comment: You should revise your idea of the dynamics of extended bodies.

Comment: Why not? At this point my ignorance meter has you at 98%. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne, write an answer and give a detailed description, if you can

Comment: I did. Your question doesn't make any sense because it expects something that physically isn't necessary and plays no role in practical tripping.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Hey, sir; can you see my answer? Is it a correct explanation? Please give feedback.

Comment: @user36790: I did read your answer and I gave you an up vote, if that helps.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Thanks for the feedback. But I am a bit worried why I was downvoted. And another user wrote momentum is associated only with the center of mass & my explanation is wrong. I don't know what to say. They don't know the dynamics of extended bodies, I think:(

Comment: @CuriousOne "There is no need for any friction between the stone and the foot in order to trip" Well in fact you DO need static friction, or else the stone will just slide along with you. The point is that static friction acts no work on either body.

Comment: @user36790: What happens to the momentum depends on whether your foot is soft or hard. Think about throwing a rubber ball against a hard wall. The ball bounces back, retains almost all of its energy (hence no energy transfer to the wall) and moves in the opposite direction. If the ball is soft (like a piece of wet clay) it would stick to the wall, in which case all of the energy gets deposited in the ball (foot) but not in the hard wall. The ball's/foot's momentum gets transferred. To me your understanding is good enough, the original question of energy  transferred is, OTOH, ill-defined.

Comment: @JoshuaLin: I think you should work through that argument a few more times because it is both patently wrong about the friction part being necessary to avoid slipping (think potential minima of hooks) and at the same time actually backs up my argument that no energy needs to be transferred. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you think of the runner as being stationary and the ground as being the thing that moved, you can think of a rock hitting a rigid object off center. A torque is imposed on the body based on the force perpendicular to the body and the distance from it's axis of rotation.

Answer (score 1):

When you move with a certain velocity, you possess what is known as **inertia of motion** which is the measure of the difficulty to avert the motion. Since you have velocity, you have an associated momentum.

Now, when your foot gets struck to the stone, by Newton's third law, the stone exerts a reactive force due to its deformation by the force applied by you. This reactive force provides sufficient impulse to stop your feet by destroying the momentum of the foot. However, as your body has still the momentum left, by Newton's first law, your body moves & eventually leans forward ultimately in a position of unstable equilibrium. This makes the great THUD!

Comment: @user77434: Have I written that torque is not acting??? Have you read the answer completely? If so, haven't you seen "**unstable equlibrium**"?? Do you what happens when a body reaches this state? Do you know that the linear terms will change by then? Gravity is providing the torque when the body reaches this position, do you know that? Isn't it implied here?? If you aren't satisfied, The answer-box is here; write your own answer!

Comment: @Daffy: Hey, can you explain me why a person leans & sometimes falls forward when a moving bus applies brakes????

Comment: @Daffy: You are skipping my question wittily. I do know the explanation & it is the same as above. BTW, thanks for downvoting:)

Comment: @Daffy: Momentum is associated with the whole body. And answer yourself the question I have asked & read any valid explanation in the net. Then come again.